# How to efficiently load large csv file into html table using flask?

Tags: python, html, csv, flask, jinja2

I'm wondering what would be the best practice to load csv data (over 60,000 rows) into html table using flask (I'm flask beginner).

I'm able to load data to html table, but it takes a very long time for the page to load in my browser. Would someone be able to recommend a better, more robust solution for my scenario? Thank you in advance!

My code so far:

`app.py`:

```
@app.route('/')
def weather_dashboard():
    filename = '/path/to/my/data.csv'
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    myData = list(data.values)
    return render_template('home.html', myData=myData)
```

`home.html`:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Sold Items</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for value in myData%}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
      <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the csv ever change?

Comment: you could create an api endpoint that supports pagination (accept offset and limit for instance) and make the html page lazy load dynamically in chunks (`axios`, `async-api`, etc..)

Comment: @Maximillian, the number of rows yes, but columns are always the same..

Comment: @Baobab1988 Are you using the `csv` as a database of some form? or is it changing external to your application?

Comment: @Maximilian, It's external. do you think it would be better to convert it into .db and try with sqlite3?

Comment: @Tibebes would you be able to share any example or give some more hints that would help me start? thanks a lot!

Comment: @Baobab1988 No, I'm wondering what purpose the `csv` serves here.  If it's changing while your app runs, but your app isn't the thing changing it, then that makes me approach your question from a different direction.

Comment: @Maximilian, i'm getting this csv file refreshed once a week. then I'm trying to put its data in my html table rows where user will be able to search through it or filter it. But separately to this html table on the same html page I want to include some other functionality of my app that involves routing and retrieving data with GET.

Comment: @Baobab1988 I'm working on writing an answer, but I'd suggest caching your csv then and only rendering the response once per csv change (my answer will include a rudimentary solution of this).

Comment: "where user will be able to search through it or filter it" I would focus on providing a good UI for querying and filtering; nobody is going to scroll through 60K rows on a page.  Note you'd still need to provide pagination for large resultsets.  Store the data in a database.

Comment: I second what @snakecharmerb said, it would be much better, if you would add some filtering functionality in your page. It can be done pretty easy with flask

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to improve performance at the cost of resource usage (RAM).  It will only update when the file's content hash changes.

```py
import csv
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

import flask


class Cache:
    template = '''<tbody>
{% for v in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ v[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ v[1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ v[2] }}</td>
    <td>{{ v[3] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>'''
    csv_file = Path(__file__).parent / 'data.csv'

    def __init__(self, app: flask.Flask):
        self._app = app
        self._cache = None
        self._filehash = None
        self()  # first-time initialization

    def __call__(self):
        filehash = self._hash_file()
        if filehash != self._filehash:
            self._filehash = filehash
            self._cache = self._render()

        return self._cache

    def _hash_file(self) -> str:
        with self.csv_file.open('rb') as f:
            md5 = hashlib.md5()
            while data := f.read(65536):  # 64kb chunks
                md5.update(data)
            return md5.hexdigest()

    def _render(self):
        with self.csv_file.open(newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            next(reader)  # skip header

            with self._app.app_context():
                return flask.render_template_string(self.template, data=reader)


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app)


@app.route('/')
def weather_dashboard():
    return flask.render_template('home.html', table_body=cache())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app.py like this code.

```
@app.route('/')
def weather_dashboard():
    filename = '/path/to/my/data.csv'
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    myData = data.values
    return render_template('home.html', myData=myData)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with pandas.to_html:

```
@app.route('/')
def weather_dashboard():
    filename = '/path/to/my/data.csv'
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    data.columns=['date','ID','Items','Sold Items']
    data.to_html(open('data.html', 'w'))
    return render_template('data.html')
```